# How to sort some data by time?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am fetching data from Firebase. I need to sort by time but its showing error of

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'seconds' of undefined\
```

This is the code how I am sorting

```
getForums(){
        this.messageService.getAllForum().pipe(map(advertisement => advertisement.sort((a :any, b: any) => b.time.seconds - a.time.seconds)
          )).subscribe((data: any)=>{
         this.advertisement = data;
         console.log(this.advertisement);


        });
}
```

And this is how I am insert data

```
    insert() {
     // the user details are updated in firebase user list
     this.forumDetails = {
       title: this.Name,
       body: this.description || '',
       time: new Date(),
       }
     console.log(this.forumDetails);
      this.messageService.createForum(this.forumDetails).then(resp => {
        console.log(resp);
        this.toast.show("Forum Created");
        this.router.navigate(["/home"]);
      });
  }
```

I need to sort data by time like in array first item will be the latest date data.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fgK4o.png)

My Question is wrong i dont have time field in all arrays thats why its showing error. Code is working fine

Comment: `console.log(time)?`

Comment: @PrashantPimpale update my question with image of console

Comment: Can you provide a stacblitz demo? So I can reproduce an issue